# ViewControl always categorized? Xpages/Notes

Tags: view, xpages, lotus-domino, categories, lotus

im having a bit of a problem with the viewcontrol in Domino Designer 9.0.
Im working on an Application that was NOT created by me. I cant ask the original developer but i have made some good expierence here so i hope for help again.
I have a view control that is categorized. At least i think its categorized but you can expand and collapse some values so i guess its categorized. And i simply dont want that. I already went in the View(not the Control) and configurated every column to "none" sorting. However the control is still categorized. I have already been googling for ages but everybody is talking about a "expandLevel" property which is simply cannot find. I know i have given you very litle information on my problem but thats all i know. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for the bad english im not a native speaker.

Sincerly, Brugen.

Comment: Try changing the underlining view or choose a different view, or clone the view and remove the category.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whats wrong with your application: As the helper- text in the column- properties of a view states on the Display Tab:

> "Expand image" and "Collapse image" can only be defined when a column is categorized, or its responses are intented.
>   **To categorize this column open the View design element to which this is bound, and choose to categorize any columns that you wish to categorize**

I just checked with an example database to be absolutely sure: The view in xpage is categorized, when the underlying view is and it is sorted only when I change the column- property. No voodoo in xpage involved.

There might be some caching issues (serverside or clientside) that prevents you from seeing the changes, but basically it should work.

The expandLevel property that you found is basically just there to tell the xpage which categories to expand / collapse by default. If can be found in the All Properties- Pane of the xpage, opening `data - data - dominoView`.

If this does not work for you, then the guy who made this xpage did something special. Then we need the source- code of your xpage to tell WHAT he did.